# The whole page scrolls to right when dragging events from the TreeView (schedule/external-drag-drop)

Tags: reactjs, scheduler, syncfusion

As anyone can notice it, in [the schedule external drag drop demo](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/demos/?&_ga=2.191361706.1836735640.1587390681-1872090167.1583251539#/material/schedule/external-drag-drop) , someone can drag the event from the TreeView list and when it get near to the right page edge then the page scrolls to the right.
Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gb8VK.jpg) showing it. 
It's occuring also in our app and it's rather annoying.
We wish there will be a fix for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Greetings from Syncfusion Support.

We have checked your reported problem that dragging a TreeView node that produces the scroller in the output web page. Currently, we don’t have any property to prevent the scroll when dragging a TreeView node. However, we have already considered this as a feature from our end. It will be included in our Volume 2 Release which is expected to be released in June 2020.

Track the below link to know the feature status.

https://www.syncfusion.com/feedback/13575/need-to-provide-the-option-to-set-the-drag-area-in-treeview-component

But, you can resolve your issue by setting the target for dragArea of TreeView’s drag object in the created event. When setting the target, you can drag the element only inside the target element. It prevents the element from scrolling exceeding that element.

Please, check out the sample with the above explained solution.

Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jqzozo-gqpyve?file=index.js

```
onCreate(){  
  this.treeObj.dragObj.dragArea = "body";  
}
```